# Linq to produce custom period in days, hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: c#, sql, linq, foreach

```
var resultsFromSql = from wb in reportContext.WorkItems
                             where wi.DateRequired >= model.FirstDate && wi.DateRequired <= model.SecondDate
                             select new
                             {
                                 wi.Reference,
                                 dateRequired = SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy", wi.DateRequired) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DatePart("mm", wi.DateRequired) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DatePart("dd", wi.DateRequired),
                                 earliestActionDate = SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy", wi.EarliestActionDate) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DatePart("mm", wi.EarliestActionDate) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DatePart("dd", wi.EarliestActionDate),
                                 mainRef = wi.MainReferenceId != 0 ? wi.MainReferenceId.ToString() : " ",
                                 subRef = wi.SecondaryReference ?? "",
                                 details = wi.DisplayDetails ?? "",
                                 createdOn = SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy", wi.CreatedOn) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DatePart("mm", wi.CreatedOn) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DatePart("dd", wi.CreatedOn),*/ /*wi.UpdatedBy,
                                 updatedOn = SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy", wi.UpdatedOn) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DatePart("mm", wi.UpdatedOn) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DatePart("dd", wi.UpdatedOn),
                                 timeTaken = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", wi.UpdatedOn, wi.CreatedOn) + " days " 
                                        /*+ SqlFunctions.DatePart("h", wi.UpdatedOn - wi.CreatedOn) + ":"
                                        + SqlFunctions.DatePart("n", wi.UpdatedOn - wi.CreatedOn) + ":"
                                        + SqlFunctions.DatePart("s", wi.UpdatedOn - wi.CreatedOn)*/,
                                 timeStuff = SqlFunctions.DatePart("h", wi.UpdatedOn /*- wi.CreatedOn*/)
                             };
```

TimeTaken and TimeStuff wont work due to DatePart not supporting hours etc, and I get other errors relating to the dateTime maths of the commented portion of timeTaken.  How can I create a timeTaken value of x days, hours, minutes and seconds which is the length of time calculated from updatedOn minus createdOn which are dateTimes.

```
/*List<T> list = new List<T>();*/
            foreach (var res in resultsFromSql.ToList())
            {
                res.timeTaken = res.CreatedOn; /*= SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", res.UpdatedOn, res.CreatedOn)#1#
            }
```

If I run a foreach afterwards I'm unable to assign values to any of the properties as the anonymous types are readonly.  How can I get my days(full days value, not remaining part of month i.e. 197days) with the leftover hours(max 24), minutes(max 60) and seconds(max 60).

Comment: Use "dd" or "d" as the first parameter to DateDiff for day. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for that, but what about the hours, mins and seconds etc and how to do it all in a Linq query or foreach

Comment: I'd have probably used a foreach and TimeSpans, but that may or may not work for you. Depends on the Types in your WorkItem objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string ConvertToDayHourMinSec(DateTime firstTime, DateTime secondTime)
    {
        var timeTaken = new TimeSpan(firstTime.Ticks - secondTime.Ticks);
        var days = timeTaken.ToString("%d"); 
        var hms = timeTaken.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        return days + " days, " + hms;
    }
```

Thanks to @Kevin's answer which lead me down the right path.  The code is a bit heavy for inline use so I created the above function which can be called with any dateTime i.e.

```
UpdatedMinusCreated = ConvertToDayHourMinSec(res.UpdatedOn, res.CreatedOn),
```

and gives the format `4 days, 03:07:42`

Answer (score 1):

Took a bit closer look at what you were doing, give this a try:

```
var resultsFromSql = from wb in reportContext.WorkItems
                         where wi.DateRequired >= model.FirstDate && wi.DateRequired <= model.SecondDate
                         select new
                         {
                             wi.Reference,
                             dateRequired = wi.DateRequired.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd"),
                             earliestActionDate = wi.EarliestActionDate.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd"),
                             mainRef = wi.MainReferenceId != 0 ? wi.MainReferenceId.ToString() : " ",
                             subRef = wi.SecondaryReference ?? "",
                             details = wi.DisplayDetails ?? "",
                             createdOn = wi.CreatedOn.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd"),
                             updatedOn = wi.UpdatedOn.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd"),
                             timeTaken = new TimeSpan(wi.UpdatedOn.Ticks - wi.CreatedOn.Ticks).Days.ToString() + " days " +
                                            new TimeSpan(wi.UpdatedOn.Ticks - wi.CreatedOn.Ticks).Hours.ToString() + ":" +
                                            new TimeSpan(wi.UpdatedOn.Ticks - wi.CreatedOn.Ticks).Minutes.ToString() + ":" +
                                            new TimeSpan(wi.UpdatedOn.Ticks - wi.CreatedOn.Ticks).Seconds.ToString()
                         };
```

Just typed this in an editor, you may need to tweak it a bit. This assumes that wi.DateRequired, wi.EarliestActionDate, wi.CreatedOn, and wi.UpdatedOn are DateTime Type. Also assumed timeStuff was experimental (trying to get it to work) and removed it.